# Laravel get all related models in one collection/array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, orm, eloquent

**Laravel 4**

Is there any easy way to get all related models in one collection (only with Eloquent)?

For example, I want to get all of the students, that is related to many classes:

First, I need to get a collection with the relations:

```
$classes = Class::with('students')->whereIn('code', ['A', 'B'])->get();
```

Then I need to go through the entire collection to merge the students:

```
$allStudents = new Collection;

foreach ($classes as $class) {
    $allStudents = $allStudents->merge($class->students);
}
```

Or if I need only one key, for example, `id` of the student, I'm doing this:

```
$allStudentsIds = [];

foreach ($classes->fetch('students') as $studentsArray) {
    $allStudentsIds = array_merge(
        $allStudentsIds, array_pluck($studentsArray, 'id')
    );
}
```

Is there a method to get only related models? Or somehow I can  make it through a request to the `Student` model?

Answer (score 0):

Query based on students and join with classes?

```
Student::select('student.*')
->join('class_student', 'class_student.student_id', '=', 'student.id')
->join('class', 'class.id', '=', 'class_student.class_id')
->whereIn('class.id', $classes)
->get();
```

Something like that.

I assumed it is a many to many relationship and class_student is the association table